# Finding the function using fundamental theorems of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

If the integral
$$
 \int_{-2x}^3 f(t) dt = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} 
$$
 find $f(\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: Have you tried something in order to solve this? Perhaps differentiating both sides?

Comment: I've tried. I differentiated both sides and used fundamental theorems of calculus. But im not sure on how to use 2x in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$2f(-2x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: @fed: Well, it's not *that* complicated. If $-2x$ is supposed to be equal to $1/4$, then you must let $x$ be equal to what?

Comment: Okay. I get it now! Thanks a lot! 